# Add SubView directly from UIButton action without having to call a Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, selector, objective-c-blocks

Is there any way I can make it so when a UIButton is pressed it adds a subview just in the one line of code that init's the action. Without having to call a @selector method that then calls that method and that method adds a subview.

For example I tried the two following attempts:

`[theButton addTarget:self.view action:@selector(addSubview:theView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

and

`[theButton addTarget:self.view action:@selector(addSubview:) withObjects:theView forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

But both failed.

————

Is my only option to call a Method that then adds the view, i.e.

```
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addTheSubview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void)addTheSubview {
    [self.view addSubview:theSubview];
}
```

Perhaps there is a way to do it with no Method by using block statements in the `addTarget` code of the UIButton? (I know little of block statements).

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Is there any way I can make it so when a UIButton is pressed it adds a
>   subview just in the one line of code that init's the action. Without
>   having to call a @selector method that then calls that method and that
>   method adds a subview.

In a word, no.

You are "[**tilting at windmills**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilting_at_windmills)".

You need your button to invoke an `IBAction` method that in turn runs several lines of code which displays the view. About the best you could do would be to install you view in the form but make it hidden, and then in your IBAction you could use a single line of code to set `view.hidden = NO`, but you still need to invoke an actual IBAction method.

A button can only ever invoke a method that takes no parameters, takes the button (the sender) as a parameter, or takes the button and the UIEvent that triggered it as 2 parameters. You can't have the button's action take some arbitrary view as a parameter. It doesn't work that way.